# How do you use a bubble sort with pointers in c++?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, bubble-sort

So here's what I have so far:

```
void sortArray(int amountOfScores, int* testScores)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < amountOfScores; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < amountOfScores-1; j++)
        {
            if(*(testScores+i) > *(testScores+j+1))
            {
                int temp = *(testScores+j);
                *(testScores+j) = *(testScores+j+1);
                *(testScores+j+1) = temp;
            }
        }
    }       
    for(int i = 0; i < amountOfScores; i++)
    {
        cout << *(testScores+i) << endl;
    }
}
```

Basically I'm trying to read in however many numbers the user wants to input, then sort them in ascending order.  Catch is I have to use pointers and I've never really understood them.  This code above works for 3 numbers, however, adding any more causes it to not sort them...I've tried trouble shooting as best I could but without any knowledge in pointers I don't know what I'm looking for.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: testScores is declared as pointer to an int, if you want to sort using int * pointers, then you nedd to pass int** into your sort function. either `int ** testScores` or `int* testScores[]`, the second form is clearer, I think.

Comment: One piece of advice: read some tutorials on pointers and what they are and how to use them with arrays.  It will make your life easier!

Comment: Is this homework? If so, tag it with the 'homework' tag. If not, why use bubble sort?

Comment: @John Knoeller: That's not true. He'd only need to pass a pointer-pointer if he were trying to change where the pointer points to, which he's not. As long as he only wants to swap around the items pointed to, a simple pointer is fine.

Comment: @Tony I've read through the chapter and a few websites, just not grasping them for some reason.

@Mark Byers Because I'm still just learning about pointers, once I'm more comfortable with them I won't be using simple sorting forms like Bubble Sort.

Comment: @sepp2k, yes but he won't be _able_ to pass an array of pointers to ints without casting.

Comment: @John Knoeller: He doesn't need (or want) to pass an an array of int pointers. Except for the fact that he mixed up i and j his code works perfectly as it is.

Comment: @sepp2k: I misunderstood the question then. Ignore me...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You problem might be here:

```
    if(*(testScores+i) > *(testScores+j+1))
```

Did you mean:

```
        if(*(testScores+j) > *(testScores+j+1))
```

(Note i replaced by j).

btw, in Bubble sort, if there are no swaps, you should break. This will cause a speed up in some cases.

Comment: Yea, so I just slammed my head on my desk.  Indeed I did mean j and not i, figured it would be something stupidly simple like that.  Thanks for the fresh set of eyes!

Comment: @Jeff: Yeah, your pointer usage seems fine. Only your typing skills need improvement :)

Answer (score 1):

Bubble sort works the same no matter if you are talking an array or a linked list (pointers).

The only catch is that rather than swapping the location of two adjacent items in an array, you are swapping pointer values between two adjacent list elements.

The algorithm is the same.

Comment: Nothing in the OP's question or code suggests that he's dealing with linked lists.

Comment: Your response assumes I paid attention enough to look at his code. Bad /. habits.